# When sending an HTTP POST with a byte [] the server responses is System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, http

I am attempting to send a simple json converted to byte [] written in C# to a Ubuntu system using curl that hits an HTTP listener written in Golang. The problem is that what is being sent appears to be System.Byte[] rather than something that could be interpreted as a byte []. I did an Encoding.UTF8.GetString of the converted byte array and it did return properly so something is missing with what or how I’m attempting to send.

C# webforms backend code

```
public class TestSID
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
       
    }
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public byte[] bytedata { get; set; }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestSID sid = new TestSID();
        sid.Number = Number.Text;

        string stringdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sid);
        byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringdata);
        SSHSubmits.SIDSubmitByte(bytedata);                     
    }
}
```

Sending to Ubuntu server which the HTTP server is running on

```
public static void SIDSubmitByte(byte[] fromSource)
    {
        using (var sshClient = ClientCreate())
        {

            sshClient.Connect();
             ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fromSource);
            string consortiumPostAddr = "http://127.0.0.1:42069/incoming/1/1/testsid";
            SshCommand curlcmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("echo -e " + fromSource + " " + "| "  + "curl --request POST --data-binary " + "@- " + consortiumPostAddr);
            curlcmd.Execute();
            sshClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Golang POST Handler case

```
case "testsid":
    fmt.Printf("SSH TestSID Connected")
    fmt.Println("The incoming is", body)
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, &testSID)
    if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                     if e, ok := err.(*json.SyntaxError); ok {
    log.Printf("syntax error at byte offset %d", e.Offset)
}
log.Printf("response: %q", body)
            }
            getNumber := testSID.Number
            if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("The number is", getNumber)
            TestSID(getNumber)
            return 200, []byte("TestSID Complete")
```

The result when sending

SSH TestSID Connected
The incoming is [83 121 115 116 101 109 46 66 121 116 101 91 93 10]
invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2021/06/09 10:16:42 syntax error at byte offset 1
2021/06/09 10:16:42 **response: "System.Byte[]**\n"
invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
The number is
Connected to TestSID DB
strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax

Using https://onlinestringtools.com/convert-bytes-to-string I find that [83 121 115 116 101 109 46 66 121 116 101 91 93 10] = Error: Error: Invalid UTF-8 detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
    SshCommand curlcmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("echo -e " + fromSource + " " + "| "  + "curl --request POST --data-binary " + "@- " + consortiumPostAddr);
```

you're asking C# to create a string representation of `fromSource` that can be used in string concatenations. It does this by calling `ToString()`.

Since ´byte[]´ doesn't have a ToString implementation, it goes down the inheritance tree and ends up at `object.ToString()` which returns the type name. In your case "System.Byte[]".

To get it to work you should convert the byte array to a string yourself using the appropriate encoding. If you want UTF-8 you could do

```
string fromSourceAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fromSource);
```

If your byte array contains binary data that can't easily be represented as a string, you might consider base64 encoding it before sending it and decoding it on the receiving end.

Comment: That definitely changed the results. Now I have to deal with what appears to be an issue in the json.

SSH TestSID ConnectedThe incoming is [123 78 117 109 98 101 114 58 49 125 10]
invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of object key string
2021/06/09 19:15:04 syntax error at byte offset 2
2021/06/09 19:15:04 response: "{Number:1}\n"
invalid character 'N' looking for beginning of object key string
The number is
Connected to TestSID DB
strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax